# Помогите разобраться с ошибкой PYTHON

Tags: python, числа

У меня задача на Степике:

> На вход программы пользователь вводит целое положительное число.
> Программа должна посчитать и вывести два числа: произведение четных и нечетных цифр числа, через пробел. В случае, если четных или нечетных цифр в числе нет, на месте произведения выводится 1.

Вот моё решение:

```
n = list(input())
chet = []
nechet = []
prodchet = 1
prodnechet = 1
for i in n:
    if int(i) % 2 == 0:
        chet.append(i)
    else:
        nechet.append(i)
if len(chet) > 0 or len(nechet) > 0:
    for i in nechet:
        prodnechet *= int(i)
    for i in chet:
        prodchet *= int(i)
elif len(chet) < 0 or len(nechet) < 0:
    prodnechet = 1
    prodchet = 1
print(prodchet, prodnechet)
```

Мне почему то выдает ошибку:

```
Failed test #5 of 7. Runtime error
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 8, in <module>
    if int(i) % 2 == 0:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

У вас попадает пустая строка в функцию int()

```
int('')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Например, добавьте в ответ объяснение, почему так происходит.

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Это происходит, видимо, потому, что на входе вы даете число вместе с пробелом, а так как пробел тоже является символом, он попадает в список и дальше к нему применяется функция `int()`.

Кстати, можно же сделать намного легче и обойтись только двумя переменными (правда, нужно тогда обработать ситуацию, когда произведение равно нулю, что я, конечно же, не сделал).

```
number = list(input());

chet = 1;
nechet = 1;

for i in number:
    if int(i) % 2 == 0:
        chet *= int(i);
        
    else:
        nechet *= int(i);
        
print(chet, nechet);
```

Comment: Почему вы умножаете на 2?

Comment: @MBo исправил, умножать надо на число, просто я переписал его и поторопился

Comment: спасибо❤️
очень помогли

Answer (score 0):

Судя по ошибке, в одном из тестов в строку кроме цифр попадают пробелы. Их надо удалить ([`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)):

```
n = list(input().strip())
...
```

**P.S.** Я не удержался и немного поколдовал над вашим решением:

```
products = [1, 1]
for d in map(int, input().strip()):
    products[d % 2] *= d
print(*products)
```

Comment: спасибо, все понял 